# HintRequest show 3 sim number

Tags: android, google-api

When `Hint` is open I got 3 mobile numbers where as device has only 2 sim inserted so how can I solve this ?

I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxtLz.jpg)

Here it is my code to fetch mobile number using `HintRequest`.

```java
public void requestHint(){

    HintRequest hintRequest=new HintRequest.Builder()
            .setHintPickerConfig(new CredentialPickerConfig.Builder().setShowCancelButton(true).build())
            .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
            .setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported(false)
            .build();

     GoogleApiClient apiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
            .build();


    PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
            apiClient, hintRequest);

    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
                RESOLVE_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RESOLVE_HINT){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Credential credential = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY);
            Toast.makeText(this, credential.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.